# Obtain from IPOPT solver: CPU times, #iterations , value of objective function and save them in a vector on Pyomo

Tags: pyomo, ipopt

I know how print these value on terminal , (ex.: `results = solver.solve(model,tee=True)`), but I want to save them in 3 variables or in a vector. The values that I need are CPU times, #iterations, the value of objective function.

Answer (score 0):

We have something very close to this in an open Pyomo PR which is a thin wrapper around IPOPT. See here (https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/contrib_parmest/pyomo/contrib/parmest/ipopt_solver_wrapper.py). I think you could easily modify this to give you what you want.